# Show/Hide div, with plain JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My CSS:

```
#a_x200{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

My JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

My Html

```
<div id="a_x200">asd</div>
<innput type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="show('a_x200');"></input>
```

Not working I think I missed something!

Comment: You're setting `visibility` in css but changing `display` in js plus some syntax errors...

Comment: #a_x200{display:none; width:200px;height:200px; background-color: black;}
Still not working

Comment: @PoWeR Can you recreate the problem in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: refer to [show or hide dom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070237/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `visibility: hidden` to hide it, then attempting to use the `display` CSS property to make it visible. They're two completely separate properties, changing one won't magically change the other.

If you want to make it visible again, change the value of the `visibility` property to `visible`:

```
document.getElementById('a_x200').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
document.getElementById('a_x200').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can try this code:**

```
HTML Code:
        <div id="a_x200" style="display:none;">asd</div>
        <input type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="showStuff('a_x200');"></input>

Java script:

<script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Try this code it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can se one example i created in jquery [Show/Hide using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/tolla/eMXrH/) .

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>

<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

your input is miss spled

Should be like this:

My JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(a_x200) {
        document.getElementById(a_x200).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

My Html

```
<div id="a_x200">asd</div>
<innput type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="showStuff('a_x200');"></input>
```

Comment: Using `document.getElementById('a_x200')` is perfectly fine, it just makes the parameter on the function totally pointless.

Comment: @PoWeR missing curly bracket in your function too.. :):)

Comment: @Anthony Grist he didnt use the parameter that was passed to his method, I changed it so it will get the id as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; // OR
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}
```

**edit**

If you notice on your button click `onclick="showStuff('a_x200');"`. you have already sent the id as a parameter to your function.. so i am taking  the parameter and using it.

in your case have the parameter but  not using it... though it does the samething...

**OR** u can do this

```
<input type="button" class="button_p_1" onclick="showStuff();"></input>  // omitting double 'n'

function showStuff() {
    document.getElementById('a_x200').style.display = 'block';
}  // missing curly bracket
```

this both does the same thing

Comment: @PoWeR He renamed the parameter on the function, and then actually passed it to the `document.getElementById()` call. The value of `id` will change, depending on what you pass as that first argument when calling `showStuff()`. If you do `showStuff('a_x200')` (like you are when the button is clicked on) then `id` will equal `'a_x200'`.