# Show/Hide script using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, show-hide

I have a show/hide script that I am using for a menu. When I click a main link it brings up a list below it. I was wondering if there is a way to alter it a bit so that when I click the link it opens but when I click the next one it closes the other one instead of leaving them all open unless you click it again to close.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list1');">
       <p>List One</p>
       </a>
       <div id="list1" style="display:none;">
         <ul>
           <li>Item One</li>
           <li>Item Two</li>
           <li>Item Three</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more what you are trying to achieve ? it is not very clear from your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS show/hide div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836848/js-show-hide-div)

Answer (score 14):

Suppose this is your code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list1');">
  <p>List One</p>
</a>
<div id="list1" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list2');">
  <p>List Two</p>
</a>
<div id="list2" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Change it to this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list1');">
  <p>List One</p>
</a>
<div id="list1" class="alist" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list2');">
  <p>List Two</p>
</a>
<div id="list2" class="alist" style="display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And make your JavaScript this:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/think123/FqqhY/).

Instead of using plain JavaScript for this, I suggest you use jQuery.

Here's how I would do it in jQuery:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  $(".list").hide();
  $("#" + id).toggle();
}
```

Comment: plus one for the jquery suggestion

Comment: The first one works great. What makes the second one, that you mentioned, better?

Comment: Is there anyway to make the link open a page within a table or div on that same page next to the menu but with up re-loading the page and having the menu close. Does this make sense?

Comment: @NiCk Well, I don't know of any performance enhancements, but it's shorter, and much easier to understand.

Comment: @NiCk And about your second question, could you explain in further detail what you mean?

Comment: I want to take the link and be able to click on it and have a pop down menu, which I have now done thanks to you. I would also like for the same link to open up some information in the table or div tag beside my menu. I have it working using <?php include("$content") ?> but of course the problem is it reloads the page again and the menu closes.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to work in older versions of IE. The div tags don't want to show when you click the links in ie 8 or older.

Answer (score 3):

I would add one more function to hide all the lists but one current:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';

    hideAllBut(id);
}

function hideAllBut(id) {
    var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
    for (var i = lists.length; i--; ) {
        if (lists[i].id != id) {
            lists[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q2E5e/

Comment: ooo, never knew coral was a valid color name. Well, you learn one thing every day, don't you?

Comment: If you don't see the benefits of this approach just ignore it and use your best.

Comment: Is it possible to display two divs at a time? For example could you click the link for list one have it display list one but also list 3 at the same time?

Comment: Excellent, this helped me finish my job. Works like a charm.