# Show and hide div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to show and hide a div with JavaScript.
does someone has a additional code? This is my code so far:

```
 <script>
 window.onload=function(){$hide.div(div)};
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="overlay"></div>
 <div class="modal">I'm the modal window!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}

.modal {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

Comment: Where is `$hide` defined?

Comment: There are at least 3 examples of how to do this ->

Comment: There are many, many examples on both Google and StackOverflow on how to show and hide divs using javascript and how to do modal dialogues. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/hide/ for starters...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide script using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288790/show-hide-script-using-javascript)

Comment: You can checkout this ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288790/show-hide-script-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript :

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){  
      for(var i = 0;i < document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].style.visibility  = "hidden";
      } 
     };
</script>
```

I recommend you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").hide();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: He didn't ask for jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Just use the css [`display`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) property for this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

And for showing it again:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JHVN/2)**