# Hiding a div and/or chaning input with something else

Tags: javascript, html, hide

How do I make a div hidden or unhidden? Is there like a simple line of code for it? because all I could find was long pieces of code.  And is there also a way to make all my input boxes in a certain div change with something else? Like 20 spaces (so there's place to write something down if you would print it out)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide script using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288790/show-hide-script-using-javascript)

Comment: If you want to move a set of divs, you can make them part of the same class and set a css style. By hidden do you want it to come out of the flow of the page? Or opacity?

Comment: Maybe just a way to remove the content of a div? That'd be some great help too :D

Comment: found it :) document.getElementById("level3").innerHTML = "";