# Show/Hide Div using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a personal website and I'm trying to have a  show/hide on click of an image, but I'm not really sure where the problem is.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menuopen">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle('menu');">
        <img src="assets/Images/menu.gif" alt="Menu">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="menu">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle(id) { 
var item = document.getElementById(id);

if(item.style.display == 'block')
item.style.display = 'none';
else
item.style.display = 'block';  }
//-->
```

As a side note, this script also did not work using plain text rather than the image, so I don't think that my problem lies there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show/Hide script using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288790/show-hide-script-using-javascript)

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I linked a very similar question.  curious why you aren't using jQuery - it makes this much easier.  Though it's totally valid to want to use vanilla JS to learn :)

Comment: Also, are there any errors on the console? Try putting `alert()`s in the function to ensure the code is reaching there.

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/R5r3f/1/**

Comment: Does JS not work offline then?

Comment: Make sure you're not using `id="menu"` for any other element. IDs must be unique. http://jsfiddle.net/R5r3f/2/

Comment: I'm not, it's a unique ID

Comment: Open your console and check for errors.

Comment: Well, then maybe you're using the `<script>` tag correctly. Please post the whole `<script>` code. (I see a `//-->` at the end of your script).

Comment: Do I have to have the menu defaulting to Display: none; then? Could that possibly be my issue?

Comment: Yes that could be the problem for the first time, because then `item.style.display` would be `undefined`. So the else block would be executed, and nothing would happen. But on clicking it again, the menu would work again. But, yes, better add `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. Just a short explanation, your function is checking if the element has a `block` value attached to it's display property which is wrong - by default this property is empty. So, rather ask for `none` or an `empty` (default) value.

```
function toggle(o) {
    var e = document.getElementById(o);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the style properties are empty/meaningless until they have been set in JavaScript. You can either set the value in JS first or you can have your JS assume the starting state.

Solution 1 - Set state from JS:

```
var s = document.getElementById('menu').style;
s.display = 'block';
function toggle() { 
   if(s.display == 'block') { s.display = 'none'; }
   else { s.display = 'block'; }
}
```

Solution 2 - Assume unset means it's visible

```
function toggle(id) { 
   var s = document.getElementById('menu').style;
   s.display = (s.display!=='block' ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't make any sense! You are saying that we should iterate all the elements in the document, on every page load and attach the `block` attribute to their style?! In other words, your function isn't a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. You say it "isn't a solution" but it has the same outcome so it is. You say it "iterate all elements...and attach block" to them; my code doesn't do that, it adds a block to one the one particular element. From a performance standpoint it's a philosophical difference. Due to the placement of getElementById, your solution (i.e. my second solution) does more work per click event, while the first solution does that work upfront so you don't have to search by Id every time. Either way, the performance hit isn't perceivable.

Comment: The thing I like about solution 1 is that to me it's more readable down the line. You have this assumption that the menu starts as a block, then switches between a block or none. My solution #1 explicitly tells this whole story. My solution #2 and your solution, don't explicitly tell that story so down the line, I feel like it's less readable and maintainable. If you have assumptions about starting points, code those assumptions in. Not only does it guarantee those starting points, but when you go back to read it, you can see that assumption.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a lot of time to analyze, but I'd recommend using an in-body function with a click trigger instead of pre-defining the function. Something like what's in the fiddle here :

[`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/j4c8h/)

Hope this helps, let me know if you want some clarification and I'll do what I can.

Comment: So you just decided to convert it to jQuery and post a link as an answer (to code that isn't even close to the question) ?

Comment: According to Adeneo, this is working, so I'm not really sure why I can't get it to work properly

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? 
Also, it does seem to work fine now that I've had a second to take a look. My guess is that you have interference somewhere else. davidkonrad pointed out your lack of {}, but that shouldn't impact functionality (it's just shorthand). My guess is there is something else impacting the functionality. Where are you loading the script? I'm sure it's in the head of your script but it's worth checking. Also, how many other scripts are on the page, if any?

Comment: You may want to change your if to be 

    item.style.display !== 'none'

Or add "Style="display: none" into your div... Otherwise it's going to require two clicks for the first toggle.