# Putting a fake loading screen to give the impression that the calculation take time?

Tags: javascript

I am writing my first Javascript-Program. I am new to this programming language, therefore I would be very thankful if you could keep the answers simple, so that I can understand them.

Here is my Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Tfwh/1/

```
function temp(form) {
var umsatz = parseFloat(form.umsatz.value, 10);
var ebit = parseFloat(form.ebit.value, 10);
umsatzrendite = (ebit / umsatz)*100 + "%";
form.umsatzrendite.value = umsatzrendite;
};
```

All it does is take 2 variables out of a form and divide them and give back the result.
I want to use many more variables, but the calculations will be done very quickly. I therefore would like to give the user the impression, that the calculation is a very complicated one and takes some seconds to post the results.

Therefore I would like to use a loading screen for 3 to 5 seconds, right after the user pushes the "calculating"-Button and of course before he gets the result.

Would be nice if someone could point me to the correct direction.

Thank you.

George

Ninjaedit: 
Btw I don't know why the Jsfiddle-Version doesn't work properly. On my local environment the calculation is done properly.

Comment: The JSFiddle doesn't work because the function `temp` is wrapped in a scope whereas the form expects it in global scope. This is something to do with JSFiddle. Add `window.temp = temp;` at the bottom of your script to export `temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is; when a user clicks the button:

1. [show a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836848/js-show-hide-div) that contains a loading image or such (tip: use [jQuery library](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp))
2. start a [timer](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)
3. when timer finishes:

   - hide the div
   - perform above function

Answer (score 0):

After the push of Calculate Button, You can use `window.setTimeout` function to call the Calculate Math Operation after 2 to 3 seconds.

You can find more information on:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Let me know if this is not clear. Can give you working example for the same.You can try it yourself on the link as well.

Answer (score 0):

}Another approach would be to use the jQuery library to add a simple effect. You should change the background color, the opacity, or some other value to give the effect of a calculation or dynamic load.

```
// change the background color to pink over 2 seconds
// ...then change it back to white
$(form).animate({backgroundColor : "pink"}, 2000).delay(2000).animate({backgroundColor : "white"}, 2000);
```

Comment: You forgot a curly bracket:

    $(form).animate({backgroundColor : "pink"}, 2000).delay(2000).animate({backgroundColor : "white"}, 2000);


Could you explain, how this works? Do I have to have a set a backgroundColor? I am not too familiar with the .animate function.

Comment: thx - you can animate anything - animate just takes a dictionary of CSS key/values. jQuery will smoothly animate the transition between the current CSS and the given CSS over (in this case) 2000ms, or 2 seconds. You can then animate back to the original value after an appropriate delay