# how to make a button on click to hide and show to boxes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to find a solution for the following problem:
I need to create a button that on click will make at once one visible block to hide and another hidden block to be visible.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance,
Cheers
Valter

Comment: Here you go: http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/hide-layer2.php

Comment: Or may be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could do that.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
<div class="type1">type 1</div>
<div class="type1">type 1</div>
<div class="type2 hidden">type 2</div>
<div class="type2 hidden">type 2</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnUpdate').on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.type1').hide();
        $('.type2').show();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/d58erzqL/

I've used .hide() and .show(), but you could also use .toggle() or manually add/remove the hidden class with .addClass('hidden') and .removeClass('hidden').  You could also go with native JavaScript functionality and try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070237/4669143

There are many options.