# Inserting <object> in current html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with an input box and a button. If a user inputs some values (12345) an object need to appear below or instead of that form (the input box and the button).

I am handling a value check through  and my whole code looks like this:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="UNESI KOD">
</form>

<button onclick="proveriKljuc()" style="margin-top:20px">Potvrdi!</button>
<script>
  function proveriKljuc() {
    if (document.getElementById("subject").value == 12345) {
      document.write(
        "<center><object id='object1' data='http://termodom.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/akcija1-1.jpg'></object></center>"
      );
    }
  }

</script>
```

Currently this code is showing a object in a new window (only a object on the page).

Also this is offtopic but if you can help, how can I handle if enter is pressed to activate function `proveriKljuc()`?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You can NEVER use document.write after page load. It will wipe the page. Instead have  div or a span and fill the innerHTML of it or appendChild of a div created using document.createElement. return false onsubmit to stop submission or make the button `type="button"` - alternatively show a hidden div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587326/how-to-show-hidden-div-after-hitting-submit-button-in-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `document.write`. If you want to replace the current form:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="UNESI KOD">
</form>
</div>

<button onclick="proveriKljuc()" style="margin-top:20px">Potvrdi!</button>
<script>
function proveriKljuc()
{
if(document.getElementById("subject").value == 12345)
{
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = "<center><object id='object1' data='http://termodom.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/akcija1-1.jpg'></object></center>";
}
}
</script>
```

If you want your object to appear under the form:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="UNESI KOD">
</form>
</div>

<button onclick="proveriKljuc()" style="margin-top:20px">Potvrdi!</button>
<script>
function proveriKljuc()
{
if(document.getElementById("subject").value == 12345)
{
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML += "<center><object id='object1' data='http://termodom.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/akcija1-1.jpg'></object></center>";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: and make button type="button" - to show example click the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: but that should not be a problem in this case as the button is outside of form.

Comment: @mplungjan [`<button>` works just as well as `<input>`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)

Comment: Thanks, i got it. Do you maby know how to fix problem with enter?

Comment: Some browsers will submit the page if not type=button if type=submit inside the form and return false on the submit, the second question is answered too

Comment: @Pacijent See my answer for the solution for both issues

Answer (score 0):

You can NEVER use document.write after page load. It will wipe the page. Instead have  div or a span and fill the innerHTML of it or appendChild of a div created using document.createElement. return false onsubmit to stop submission or make the button `type="button"` - alternatively show a hidden div [How to show hidden div after hitting submit button in form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587326/how-to-show-hidden-div-after-hitting-submit-button-in-form)

I cannot show a working example because stacksnippets do not support submit

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {
    if (this.elements["subject"].value == 12345) {
      document.getElementById("objContainer").innerHTML = "<center><object id='object1' data='http://termodom.rs/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/akcija1-1.jpg'></object></center>";
    }
    return false; // ignore submit
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="UNESI KOD">
  <button type="submit" style="margin-top:20px">Potvrdi!</button>
</form>
<div id="objContainer"></div>
```