# How to show an HTML page of a submit form in a new div

Tags: html, asp.net, opencart

I have a submit form for my customers to track their orders with a tracking code. I want to show the result of order status which is checking from the shipping company's website.

```css
input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #dd0017;
}

input[type=submit]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #dd0017;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div align="left" style="background-color:rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);padding:15px 0px 15px 5px;border-radius: 5px; border:1px solid #ff60cd;"><img align="left" alt="Sürat Kargo Takip" src="image\PNGLER\surat-kargo-takip-icon-200x40.png" style="float:none;" /></div>

  <form action="http://www.suratkargo.com.tr/kargoweb/bireysel.aspx" align="left" onsubmit="window.open('','top','resizable=1, scrollbars=1,width=790,left=25,top=25')" target="top">&nbsp;
    <h2><label for="takipnoalani">Takip NO :</label></h2>
    <input id="takipnoalani" name="no" placeholder="Kargo Takip Numaranızı Yazınız..." type="text" />
    <input name="action" style="font-size:16px;float:right;" type="submit" value="Getir" />&nbsp;</form>
</div>

<div id="show_result" style="border:2px solid red;">
  I want to show the result of query here<br/>But I couldn't :( <br/> And it would be better if this red bordered div is not shown until the customer click the "Getir" button.
</div>
```

My code is opening it in a new page. However, I want to show it on the same page exactly under that form with a new (or existing but hidden) div. I don't know if it is possible or not. I looked at every question similar to this, but couldn't find a solution.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: You could always post to the same page that the form is on, and then output the data based on a conditional inside the ASPX.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, @Obsidian Age . Sorry, I couldn't understand..."based on a conditional inside the ASPX". My website is based on opencart. And I am very new to programming.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with ASPX myself -- I just noticed the `.aspx` in your `<form action>`. In PHP, it would be something like `if (!empty($_POST)) { // show form }`. For further help, you may need to provide a bit more information about exactly how your code is structured and what exactly you have the ability to modify.

Comment: @Obsidian Age . You can assume me as a beginner :) I can only read and edit the codes for now. For my question, I am looking for something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587326/how-to-show-hidden-div-after-hitting-submit-button-in-form

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Ajax to load the content and show it in form. Note I commented out the part which I use Ajax to load the content from the action because the action is not available here but it should be pretty straightforward.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result = "Result from your action.";
  
  $('#form1').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     
     $('#show_result').html("Result will show up here").slideDown('slow');
     
     /*
     var $form = $(this);
     $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data){
        $('#show_result').html("Result will show up here").slideDown('slow');
     });*/
     
     return false;
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #dd0017;
}

input[type=submit]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #dd0017;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div align="left" style="background-color:rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);padding:15px 0px 15px 5px;border-radius: 5px; border:1px solid #ff60cd;"><img align="left" alt="Sürat Kargo Takip" src="image\PNGLER\surat-kargo-takip-icon-200x40.png" style="float:none;" /></div>

  <form action="http://www.suratkargo.com.tr/kargoweb/bireysel.aspx" align="left" onsubmit="window.open('','top','resizable=1, scrollbars=1,width=790,left=25,top=25')" target="top" id="form1">&nbsp;
    <h2><label for="takipnoalani">Takip NO :</label></h2>
    <input id="takipnoalani" name="no" placeholder="Kargo Takip Numaranızı Yazınız..." type="text" />
    <input name="action" style="font-size:16px;float:right;" type="submit" value="Getir" />&nbsp;</form>
</div>

<div id="show_result" style="display:none;border:2px solid red;">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, it opens a new blank page and it is only written "Result from your action." in the red bordered div. There is no results from shipping company. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it opens a blank page you've probably missed something in the code. Either you've forgotten to add the `id` for the form (I added that myself, your form didn't have an id) or there's something in your javascript. In the code above, I handle the `submit` of the form and tell it to don't submit and I get the content from the form via Ajax and show it on the box.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need help. If this has solved your problem make sure to set it as the solution by clicking the check mark next to vote

Answer (score 0):

After I searched for hours, I found a similar question here:

[Similar Question but opening a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218245/jquery-submit-form-and-then-show-results-in-an-existing-div)

And design it for my solution.
Thanks to everyone. Here is my solution:

```js
$('#kargotakip').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#sonucgoster').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;   
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    resize: vertical;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    color: #FFF;
 background-color: #dd0017;
}

input[type=submit]:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color:#dd0017;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div align="left" style="background-color:rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);padding:15px 0px 15px 5px;border-radius: 5px; border:1px solid #ff60cd;"><img align="left" alt="Sürat Kargo Takip" src="image\PNGLER\surat-kargo-takip-icon-200x40.png" style="float:none;" /></div>

<form id="kargotakip" method="GET" action="http://www.suratkargo.com.tr/kargoweb/bireysel.aspx" align="left" >&nbsp;
 <h2><label for="takipnoalani">Takip NO :</label></h2>
 <input type="text" id="takipnoalani" name="no" placeholder="Kargo Takip Numaranızı Yazınız..." />
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Getir" style="font-size:16px;float:right;" />&nbsp;
</form>

</div>
<div id="sonucgoster" style="background-color:rgba(241, 98, 114, 0.25);border-radius: 5px; border:1px solid #ff60cd;"></div>
```