# How I can hide div without using runat server from c# code

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have two conditions, I want to hide and show a `div` with javascript or with c# code. Using `runat="server"`, I am able to hide the div with C#. Is it possible to hide the `div` with javascript? I tried the following:

```
<div id="divpassword" runat="server" style="display: none;" >
----
----
</div>

document.getElementById('<%= divpassword.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Try adding `clientidmode="static"` to your div

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, I've used this method many times. Try looking at the source code in your browser to see what `<%= divpassword.ClientID %>` actually puts in the call to `getElementById`, if that looks OK then use the JavaScript console to query what `document.getElementById('copy the id from view source')` is, and then add `.style.display` to see what the display tag is. You may find you have a typo, or something simple which is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `runat="server"` and also hide the div from javascript using `clientidmode="static"`.

```
<div id="divpassword" runat="server" clientidmode="static" style="display: none;" >
----
----
</div>

document.getElementById('divpassword').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Are you loading your javascript at the end of the body tag?

Answer (score 0):

It can be very easily done if you use jQuery.

```
$( "#divpassword" ).hide();
```

And if you need to do it in pure java script, the following link might help - 
[Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Appriciate, if you can make me more clear on what was unnecessary, was't the answer is solving the problem?. Is there's anything I interpreted incorrect?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Thanks for your reply. That is why I have added link for using JS. As it is not clear if OP is using jQuey or not, even if not, this gives an additional facet to it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can go many ways.

**Way #1:**

```
<div id="divpassword" runat="server" style="display: none;" >
----
----
</div>
<script language="javascript">document.getElementById('<%= divpassword.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';</script>
```

**Way #2:**

```
<div id="divpassword" runat="server" clientidmode="static" style="display: none;" >
----
----
</div>
<script language="javascript">document.getElementById('divpassword').style.display = 'block';</script>
```