# HTML anh Javascript ADD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code

```
sTAT **javascript**
```

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("item-wrapper");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
this.classList.toggle("selected");
this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
}
});
```

css

```
.accordion-menu{
    list-style: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;
}
.accordion-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: arial;
}

.accordion-menu a:hover,
.accordion-menu a:visited,
.accordion-menu a:active,
.accordion-menu a:focus{
    background: none;
}

.accordion-menu li {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none ;
}
ul.accordion-menu>li>.item-wrapper,li.item-wrapper {
    background: url("../images/bullet-1.png") no-repeat scroll 12px 14px , #242729 repeat-x 0 0;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0px 35px;
    margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #181818;
    border-top: 1px solid #454545;
    position: relative;
}
ul.accordion-menu>li>.item-wrapper:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
ul.accordion-menu>li>.item-wrapper.selected:after{
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
/*Hover Level1*/
ul.accordion-menu> li >.item-wrapper:hover,li.item-wrapper:hover{
    background: url("../images/bullet-1.png") no-repeat scroll 12px -45px , url(../images/vertical.png) repeat-x 0 0;

}
ul.accordion-menu> li >.item-wrapper:before,li.item-wrapper:before{
    content: "";
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    width:5px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #636363;
}
ul.accordion-menu> li >.item-wrapper:hover:before,
ul.accordion-menu> li.current >.item-wrapper:before,li.item-wrapper:hover:before{
    background-color: #FF8400;
}

.accordion-menu>li>.item-wrapper a,li.item-wrapper a {
    font-size: 133.3%;

}

.accordion-menu  li .ul-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
div.ul-wrapper ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
div.ul-wrapper > ul > li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9C8383;
    background: url(../images/li.png) no-repeat 10px 12px;
    background-color: #1F1C1C;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 26px;
}
div.ul-wrapper ul ul > li {
    background: url(../images/bullet2.png) no-repeat 23px 12px;
}

/* Hover level2*/
div.ul-wrapper > ul > li:hover,
div.ul-wrapper > ul > li.current{
    background: url(../images/li-hover.png) no-repeat 10px 12px;`enter code here`
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}
div.ul-wrapper > ul > li:hover div.item-wrapper{
    background: none;border-bottom: none;}
div.ul-wrapper > ul ul > li:hover{
    background-color: #262525;
    background: url(../images/bullet2-hover.png) no-repeat 23px 12px;
}
.accordion-menu  li ul ul .item-wrapper {
    padding-left: 24px;
}
.accordion-menu li ul li.current  .item-wrapper,
.accordion-menu li ul li.open  .item-wrapper{
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

.accordion-menu li:last-child,.accordion-menu>li.last {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.accordion-menu{
    text-align: left;
}

.accordion-menu a{
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="module_menu">
    <div class="module-content clearfix">
        <ul class="accordion-menu" id="demo-menu">
            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <a href="/category1">Category 1</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="item-wrapper">
                    <a href="/category2">Category 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="ul-wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/category2/2013-01-16-23-09-22">Sub category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/category2/2013-01-16-23-09-23">Sub category 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="item-wrapper">
                        <a href="/category3">Category 3</a> 
                </div>
                <div class="ul-wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/category3/2013-01-16-23-09-22">Sub category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/category3/2013-01-16-23-09-23">Sub category 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-wrapper">
                <a href="/category4">Category 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

fg

now I want to add conditions that, clicking the item-wrapper div to show the card, the interest is more behind it must be ul-wrapper div tag in javascript 
, then how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you're asking exactly but after looking at your code, I think I may have a solution for you.

Adding the class "show" to your ul-wrapper doesn't tell the DOM to show that element. For that, you need to use the "display" attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/65x06x7m/

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("item-wrapper");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("selected");
        this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
        }   
}
```

reference: [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)