# Javascript could show hidden div

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What needed to achieve is by clicking the preview button (ASP button, which calls another function), the hidden preview section shows. But it didn't work by the below codes... not sure what I missed.

In the `.aspx`

```
    <style>
    #PreviewSection {display:none;}

</style>
```

in the script, (edited to point to btPreview, but still not working... )

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var previewbt = document.getElementById('btPreview');
    previewbt.addEventListener('click',function(){
        PreviewSection.style.display = "block";
        })

</script>
```

the html:

```
    <div class ="container" id="InputSection">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:60%">
                    <p>The Question</p>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please fill in Question." ControlToValidate="TBQuestion" CssClass="alert-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBQuestion" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100000" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <asp:Button ID="btPreview" runat="server" Text="Preview" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btPreview_Click"/>

</div>

<hr />

<div class="container" id="PreviewSection">
    <h3> The preview of the content.</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    Question: <asp:Label ID="LbPrevQuestion" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066CC"></asp:Label><br />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="BtSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn" OnClick="BtSubmit_Click" />
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is `PreviewSection`in ` PreviewSection.style.display`

Comment: can you add the HTML code?

Comment: does the previewsectionID button added dynamically after page is loaded?

Comment: @user2181397 It is a container class. as below,
<div class="container" id="PreviewSection">
    <h3> The preview of the content.</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 Question: <asp:Label ID="LbPrevQuestion" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066CC"></asp:Label><br />

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="BtSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn" OnClick="BtSubmit_Click" />
</div>

Comment: Nobody can click on a hidden div. Do opacity=0; to hide + still clickable

Comment: How can you click on `PreviewSection` if it is hidden by default? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: the preview button is always visible... when you hit the button, the preview section shows, at least supposed to.

Comment: Where is preview button I do not see it in your question? Please upload the complete code rather than we trying to figure out the missing codes.

Comment: I think this question was already [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @Win the code is uploaded.

Comment: @Digger Why do you want to use ***ASP.Net Button*** for ***btPreview*** which will end up posting back to server? Could it be ***div tag or simple html button***?

Comment: @Win yes, it just a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you want:

**Edited** to add your modification after my first post.

```js
var BtPreview = document.getElementById('BtPreview');
BtPreview.addEventListener('click', function() {
  PreviewSection.style.display = "block";
})

var BtSubmit = document.getElementById('BtSubmit');
BtSubmit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  PreviewSection.style.display = "none";
  InputSection.style.display = "none";
})

var btPreview_Click = function() {
  console.log('Do something else for Preview.');
};

var btSubmit_Click = function() {
  console.log('Do something else for Submit.');
};
```

```css
#PreviewSection {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="InputSection">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:60%">
          <p>The Question</p>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please fill in Question." ControlToValidate="TBQuestion" CssClass="alert-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TBQuestion" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100000" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button ID="BtPreview" runat="server" Text="Preview" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btPreview_Click()">Button Preview</button>

</div>

<hr />

<div class="container" id="PreviewSection">
  <h3> The preview of the content.</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Question:
          <asp:Label ID="LbPrevQuestion" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066CC"></asp:Label>
          <br />

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button ID="BtSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btSubmit_Click()">Button Submit</button>
</div>
```

This will be the solution for ASP:

```
<div class="container" id="InputSection">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:60%">
          <p>The Question</p>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please fill in Question." ControlToValidate="TBQuestion" CssClass="alert-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TBQuestion" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="100000" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <asp:Button ID="BtPreview" runat="server" Text="Preview" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btPreview_Click()"/>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container" id="PreviewSection">
  <h3> The preview of the content.</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Question:
          <asp:Label ID="LbPrevQuestion" runat="server" Text="" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066CC"></asp:Label>
          <br />

        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <asp:Button ID="BtSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btSubmit_Click()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Teocci, thanks for the reply. as you can see from the html code I uploaded later, the preview button is located at the bottom of the upper section, the lower section is hidden when the page is loaded. When I finish working with the upper section, i hit the preview button, then the preview section shows up

Comment: @Digger post a modification to the first version. Hope is helpful.

Comment: Hi Teocci, I can see from the code snippet, it is working and it is what I need, but when I transplant to the file, it has a incompatible issue of the html button and asp.net button. Do you have a solution for that? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Display:none is misleading. Its not just not displayed, its not part of the page. So you cannot click on it. Use opacity:

```
#previewSection{
  opacity:0;
 }
```

Heres the right js:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var previewsectionID = document.getElementById('PreviewSection');
 previewsectionID.addEventListener('click',function(){ 
previewsectionID.style.opacity = 1; });
 </script>
```

Comment: very strangely, the opacity doesn't work neither... yes, it is hidding, but it couldn't be seen when clicked.