# How to close multiple divs independed from each other. javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I built a row of 4 buttons to open 4 divs, one at a time. The user can switch between the 4 divs by clicking these buttons. But, the user must be able to close this divs again, independed from each other. That means if the user clicks one of these buttons he must be able to close it again with one "closing-button" only. This button should be included to the row of 4. 
So there will be 4 buttons to open and switch between the divs like a gallery
And one button to close whichever div is shown.

I would be very very happy if someone could help me, please!!!

```js
window.show = function(elementId) { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        elements[i].className = "hidden";
    
    document.getElementById(elementId).className = "";
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.designbutton {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #266786;
 background:none;
 background-image: none;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-color:#266786;
 border-bottom:hidden;
 border-right:hidden;
}
#id1 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:30px;
 background-color:#33CC99;
 padding-left:90px;
 padding-right:90px;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:660px;
 width: 724px;
 color: #266786;
 line-height:1.65;
 text-align:center;
}
#id2 {
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: ##444444;
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 line-height:1.65;
 margin-top:50px;
}
#id3 {
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: ##444444;
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 line-height:1.65;
 margin-top:50px;
}
#id4 {
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: ##444444;
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 line-height:1.65;
 margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id1');">Economic Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id2');">Logistic Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id3');">Industrial Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id4');">Financial Center</button>



<div id="id1" class="hidden">
<p><b>El idem sae.</b></p>
<p>Id et fugit officto dolupta spicide il ipsant arum et oditaquia se cullore nistiistin nonsequae qui corem quibust, quisciisti culluptatur sedi testrum sectur?
Odipsunto venist occus issitae storepro iumqui volorat ionsedis nonem audi vellit faceaquiae. Nam dolupti re eos iumquiaecus, ullorib eritatq uaernatur, nonsequi impelest 
fugitamet quias vella sit ducidus dolupta estior molore, quas rem adisquam, quia volecae natiis arcitium etur sim inum eost pore voluptat quamusae nonsequi rerum sedit, quae. 
Sedicimaios et fuga. Accabo. Empore num aut istio. Minum que inveliaest, ut accus recatiisvendam, sitio. Ent ut ut ratemperum erfernatio ommolo occuptatur rest perereptae 
nempore odioriberro qui dellatq uiaspelit opta cum acest, etur? Num enihil moloritatur, tem corenias rehendit rero est aut et verum re nossum voluptaquae dis eaquae. Re ea 
consequ idisquasim vendebi tiisquatur solupta ssequaspero idunt perempor sam qui ulligent. Ecepe landi tet harchic iliquun tibus. Ebit ut ulluta ad et ut que expereictis 
arion eicabor epernatur? Optiaep erfero con re vendam rerume nullaccum rerspic to blaboria que vendandant.</p></div>

<div id="id2" class="hidden">
<b>Ommolo occuptatur.</b><br><br>
Ent ut ut ratemperum erfernatio ommolo occuptatur rest perereptae 
nempore odioriberro qui dellatq uiaspelit opta cum acest, etur? Num enihil moloritatur, tem corenias rehendit rero est aut et verum re nossum voluptaquae dis eaquae. Re ea 
consequ idisquasim vendebi tiisquatur solupta ssequaspero idunt perempor sam qui ulligent. Ecepe landi tet harchic iliquun tibus. Ebit ut ulluta ad et ut que expereictis 
arion eicabor epernatur? Optiaep erfero con re vendam rerume nullaccum rerspic to blaboria que vendandant.</div>

<div id="id3" class="hidden">
<b>Idunt perempor.</b><br><br>
Nam dolupti re eos iumquiaecus, ullorib eritatq uaernatur, nonsequi impelest 
fugitamet quias vella sit ducidus dolupta estior molore, quas rem adisquam, quia volecae natiis arcitium etur sim inum eost pore voluptat quamusae nonsequi rerum sedit, quae. 
Sedicimaios et fuga. Accabo. Empore num aut istio. Minum que inveliaest, ut accus recatiisvendam, sitio. Ent ut ut ratemperum erfernatio ommolo occuptatur rest perereptae 
nempore odioriberro qui dellatq uiaspelit opta cum acest, etur? Num enihil moloritatur, tem corenias rehendit rero est aut et verum re nossum voluptaquae dis eaquae. Re ea 
consequ idisquasim vendebi tiisquatur solupta ssequaspero idunt perempor sam qui ulligent. Ecepe landi tet harchic iliquun tibus. Ebit ut ulluta ad et ut que expereictis 
arion eicabor epernatur? Optiaep erfero con re vendam rerume nullaccum rerspic to blaboria que vendandant.
</div>

<div id="id4" class="hidden">
<b>Optiaep erfero</b><br><br>
Id et fugit officto dolupta spicide il ipsant arum et oditaquia se cullore nistiistin nonsequae qui corem quibust, quisciisti culluptatur sedi testrum sectur?
Odipsunto venist occus issitae storepro iumqui volorat ionsedis nonem audi vellit faceaquiae. Nam dolupti re eos iumquiaecus, ullorib eritatq uaernatur, nonsequi impelest 
fugitamet quias vella sit ducidus dolupta estior molore, quas rem adisquam, quia volecae natiis arcitium etur sim inum eost pore voluptat quamusae nonsequi rerum sedit, quae. 
Sedicimaios et fuga. Accabo. Empore num aut istio. Minum que inveliaest, ut accus recatiisvendam, sitio. Ent ut ut ratemperum erfernatio ommolo occuptatur rest perereptae 
nempore odioriberro qui dellatq uiaspelit opta cum acest, etur? Num enihil moloritatur, tem corenias rehendit rero est aut et verum re nossum voluptaquae dis eaquae. Re ea 
consequ idisquasim vendebi tiisquatur solupta ssequaspero idunt perempor sam qui ulligent. Ecepe landi tet harchic iliquun tibus. Ebit ut ulluta ad et ut que expereictis 
arion eicabor epernatur? Optiaep erfero con re vendam rerume nullaccum rerspic to blaboria que vendandant.
</div>
```

Comment: how about creating a function for the button which when clicked just displays the body and hides it when clicked again? Here try out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript).

Comment: @Edie31 You now have 3 answers, please accept the one solving your issue the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the shown element

```
...
document.getElementById(elementId).className = "shown";
...
```

and on click of the close button, you may hide it again.

```
window.hide = function() { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("shown");
    elements[0].className = "hidden";
}
```

```js
window.show = function(elementId) { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("shown");
    if (elements.length > 0)
        elements[0].className = "hidden";
    
    document.getElementById(elementId).className = "shown";
}

window.hide = function() { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("shown");
    if (elements.length > 0)
        elements[0].className = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.designbutton {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #266786;
 background:none;
 background-image: none;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-color:#266786;
 border-bottom:hidden;
 border-right:hidden;
}
#id1 {
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:30px;
 background-color:#33CC99;
 padding-left:90px;
 padding-right:90px;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:660px;
 width: 724px;
 color: #266786;
 line-height:1.65;
 text-align:center;
}
#id2 {
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: ##444444;
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 line-height:1.65;
 margin-top:50px;
}
#id3 {
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: ##444444;
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 line-height:1.65;
 margin-top:50px;
}
#id4 {
 height:auto;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: ##444444;
 position:absolute;
 left:30px;
 line-height:1.65;
 margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some other div</div>

<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id1');">Economic Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id2');">Logistic Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id3');">Industrial Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="show('id4');">Financial Center</button>
<button class="designbutton" type="button" onclick="hide();">Close</button>

<div id="id1" class="hidden">
  <p><b>El idem sae.</b></p>
  <p>Id et fugit officto dolupta spicide il ipsant arum et oditaquia se cullore nistiistin nonsequae qui corem quibust, quisciisti culluptatur sedi testrum sectur?</p></div>

<div id="id2" class="hidden">
  <b>Ommolo occuptatur.</b><br><br>
  Ent ut ut ratemperum erfernatio ommolo occuptatur rest perereptae 
  nempore odioriberro qui dellatq uiaspelit opta cum acest, etur?</div>

<div id="id3" class="hidden">
  <b>Idunt perempor.</b><br><br>
  Nam dolupti re eos iumquiaecus, ullorib eritatq uaernatur, nonsequi impelest 
  fugitamet quias vella sit ducidus dolupta estior molore.
</div>

<div id="id4" class="hidden">
  <b>Optiaep erfero</b><br><br>
  Id et fugit officto dolupta spicide il ipsant arum et oditaquia se cullore nistiistin nonsequae qui corem quibust, quisciisti culluptatur sedi testrum sectur?
</div>
```

*I would highly recommend to have a look at [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) as it makes life with JS much easier. Furthermore binding a method to window is a bit overpowered, as `show` is a very common word and may be overridden by other modules.*

Comment: Hi ppasler thats very much what i need! Thank you all for ur fast answers u solved my problem very professional, thx!

Comment: @Edie31 You may accept the answer and show others that your issue is solved: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: But, now i have the problem that it hides all other divs as well which i have on that website. But the close button should only close one of this 4 divs!! Thats a big issue, Can somebody help me, thx.

This button tag says close all divs on that website.
<button class="designbutton1" type="button" onclick="hide();">Map</button>
I think in "hide(…) there must be the id of the divs which have to be hidden.

Comment: I added it to my already built website, then now the links are not working. Instead to show the divs, it hides all remaining divs as well!

Comment: @Edie31 I modified the code to only hide divs with the class `hidden`. It now shouldn't hide other divs.

Comment: thanks for your modification. Now, the button dont work at all anymore. They dont close all other divs on the webpage and dont open these 4 divs which they have to. I think thats because of the javascript.
U wrote me this: 
"I would highly recommend to have a look at jQuery as it makes life with JS much easier. Furthermore binding a method to window is a bit overpowered, as show is a very common word and may be overridden by other modules."
Which javascript code would u recommend for me?
"binding a method to window is a bit overpowered" What is better then "window"?

Comment: Its working very good. Thanks for your help. I did a misstake but i found out.
Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, give all `divs` a common class, like `divs`

Then on button click,use following

```
$(".divs").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the simplest thing.. add a common class to all your div you want to close and on close button click addClass hide to it. I have done it in a simple looking jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f96cxs3r/

Html will be looking like

```
<div class="firstDiv">
 <div class="onebox gallery hide"></div>
 <div class="openBoxone"><button>Open</button></div>
</div>
<div class="secondDiv">
 <div class="twobox gallery hide"></div>
 <div class="openBoxtwo"><button>Open</button></div>
</div>
<div class="thirdDiv">
  <div class="threebox gallery hide"></div>
  <div class="openBoxthree"><button>Open</button></div>
</div>

<div class="closeButton">
   <div><button>Close</button></div>
</div>
```

Css will look like

```
.hide{display:none;}
.onebox{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;}
.twobox{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid green;}
.threebox{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid blue;}
.firstDiv,.secondDiv,.thirdDiv{display:inline-block;width:250px;} 
.closeButton{text-align:center;padding:20px;}
```

And js will be

```
$(".openBoxone button").on("click",function(){
   $(".onebox").removeClass("hide");
});
$(".openBoxtwo button").on("click",function(){
   $(".twobox").removeClass("hide");
});
$(".openBoxthree button").on("click",function(){
  $(".threebox").removeClass("hide");
});

$(".closeButton button").on("click",function(){
  $(".gallery").addClass("hide");
});
```