# How to close all other divs when a new button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button group with 5 buttons. I wanted onclick event of the button to toggle 5 different divs. Clicking on button 1 opened/closed div 1, clicking on button 2 opened/closed div 2 and so on. The divs are simply texts here.

1st click on a button --> Shows the div
2nd click on the button --> Hides the div

However, when I click  a button only once and it’s div displays and I click another button, the other div stacks on top of the first div.  I can close the 1st div if I click its button twice but I want the divs to close even if a different button is clicked.  How can I achieve that?

I have attached jsfiddle for what I have so far.

I saw similar question posted couple of times but none of the solution seemed fit for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
  function togglediv(id) {
            var div = document.getElementById(id);
            div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
        }
```

```html
<div class="myButtons">
  <div class="btn-group" id="MatchingEntitiesButtons">

  <button id="Button1" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('NamesTable')" type="button" > List of Names </button>

  <button id="Button2" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('PhoneTable')" type="button"> List of Address </button>

  <button  id="Button3" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('AddressTable')" type="button" > List of Phone#</button>

  <button id="Button4" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('GradesTable')" type="button"> List of Grades</button>

  <button id="Button5" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('SchoolTable')" type="button"> List of Schools </button>  

  </div>
</div>

<div id ="NamesTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Names </div>
<div id ="PhoneTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Address </div>
<div id ="AddressTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Phone# </div>
<div id ="GradesTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Grades </div>                  
<div id ="SchoolTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">School </div>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier by using a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close multiple divs independed from each other. javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996381/how-to-close-multiple-divs-independed-from-each-other-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop through all the DIVs. If it's the specified DIV, toggle it, otherwise hide it.

```js
function togglediv(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".TableBody").forEach(function(div) {
    if (div.id == id) {
      // Toggle specified DIV
      div.style.display = div.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    } else {
      // Hide other DIVs
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="myButtons">
  <div class="btn-group" id="MatchingEntitiesButtons">

    <button id="Button1" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('NamesTable')" type="button"> List of Names </button>

    <button id="Button2" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('PhoneTable')" type="button"> List of Address </button>

    <button id="Button3" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('AddressTable')" type="button"> List of Phone#</button>

    <button id="Button4" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('GradesTable')" type="button"> List of Grades</button>

    <button id="Button5" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('SchoolTable')" type="button"> List of Schools </button>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="NamesTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Names </div>
<div id="PhoneTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Address </div>
<div id="AddressTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Phone# </div>
<div id="GradesTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">Grades </div>
<div id="SchoolTable" class="TableBody" style="display:none">School </div>
```

Comment: +1 for this nice code. Hi, I am making a non-profitable, non-commercial website to record different lectures given by a group of mathematics research students.  I noticed that your code has many silent features, like the content of each button sharing the same display; and even the code of content of a button and the code of the position of the button can be anywhere (unlike some other code to show read more/less).

Comment: These all extraordinary features will perfectly match the code of our website.  So, can I use your code after several modifications with giving the proper credit? Proper credit means there will be a clear indication of where I am using your code, who is the author of the code, from where I got this code, and permission (if you grant at all!) Thank you so much.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing for the licensing terms for code posted on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Using a class would make this a lot easier. You can select the elements with the active class and remove it.

```js
function togglediv(id) {

  var div = document.getElementById(id);

  document.querySelectorAll(".TableBody.active").forEach(function(elem) {
    if (elem !== div) elem.classList.remove("active");
  });

  // toggle the class to the section that was clicked.
  div.classList.toggle("active");

}
```

```css
.TableBody {
  display: none;
}

.TableBody.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myButtons">
  <div class="btn-group" id="MatchingEntitiesButtons">

    <button id="Button1" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('NamesTable')" type="button"> List of Names </button>

    <button id="Button2" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('PhoneTable')" type="button"> List of Address </button>

    <button id="Button3" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('AddressTable')" type="button"> List of Phone#</button>

    <button id="Button4" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('GradesTable')" type="button"> List of Grades</button>

    <button id="Button5" class="roundBtns" onclick="togglediv('SchoolTable')" type="button"> List of Schools </button>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="NamesTable" class="TableBody">Names </div>
<div id="PhoneTable" class="TableBody">Address </div>
<div id="AddressTable" class="TableBody">Phone# </div>
<div id="GradesTable" class="TableBody">Grades </div>
<div id="SchoolTable" class="TableBody">School </div>
```

Without using the class, you can just use a loop and set it to be hidden

```
document.querySelectorAll(".TableBody")
  .forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  })
```

This code is not going to toggle. If you need to toggle, it is as simple as checking to see if the element is the current one you have.

```
var active = doucument.getElementById(id);
document.querySelectorAll(".TableBody")
  .forEach(function (elem) {
    if (elem !== active) {
      elem.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't toggle the item off if you click it a second time.

Comment: @CodeBreaker Isn't it supposed to hide the DIV if you click it twice?

Comment: So they call toggle and use same idea like the last example

Comment: the above code worked but like @Barmar said, it did not hide the div when I clicked it twice. Thanks a lot though. I understood what I was missing.

Comment: Edited it to toggle.... move a line of code, switched add to toggle, and added an if check.,

Answer (score 0):

Hide all the `div` elements when any button gets clicked and then display just the one that needs displaying.

But, change your approach a bit:

- Don't use inline HTML event attributes, such as `onclick`. There are
  [a bunch of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) not to use this 25+ year old technique that just
  will not die.
- Use [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to be able to set up a single event handler, but
  react according to which specific button got clicked.
- Get rid of `id`s. Using `id`s makes your code brittle because you
  need to constantly update the code to account for new elements.
- Don't use inline styles - - use CSS classes instead. This eliminates
  redundant code and makes for overriding applied styles easier.

```js
var clickedBtnIndex = null;
var shownDiv = null;

// Get all the buttons and divs into Arrays:
let buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".roundBtns"));
let divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".TableBody"));

// Set up a single click event handler on the parent element of the buttons
document.querySelector(".btn-group").addEventListener("click", function(evt){ 

  // evt.target is a reference to the specific button that triggered the event
  clickedBtnIndex = buttons.indexOf(evt.target); // Get the index of the clicked button within its group

  // If a button was clicked
  if(evt.target.classList.contains("roundBtns")){
     
     // Loop over the divs
     divs.forEach(function(div){
        // Check to see if it is currently being shown
        if(!div.classList.contains("hidden")){
           shownDiv = div;
        }
     });
  
     hideAll();  // Hide all the divs
     
     // Show/hide just the one that was clicked
     if(divs[clickedBtnIndex] === shownDiv){
       divs[clickedBtnIndex].classList.add("hidden");
       shownDiv = null;
     } else {
       divs[clickedBtnIndex].classList.remove("hidden");  
     }
     
     // Store a reference to the index of the button within its group that was clicked
     clickedBtnIndex = buttons.indexOf(evt.target);
  }

});

// This will hide all the divs
function hideAll(){
  // Loop over the array
  divs.forEach(function(div){
    div.classList.add("hidden");  // Add the hidden class
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="myButtons">
  <div class="btn-group" id="MatchingEntitiesButtons">
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Names</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Address</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Phone#</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Grades</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Schools</button>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="TableBody hidden">Names</div>
<div class="TableBody hidden">Address</div>
<div class="TableBody hidden">Phone#</div>
<div class="TableBody hidden">Grades</div>                  
<div class="TableBody hidden">School</div>
```

But to really make this much simpler, get rid of the separate divs to be shown or hidden and just use one div as a placeholder. Then, just change the contents of that single `div`.

```js
// Store the data that will need to be displayed in an object that
// has properties that store the arrays of actual data
var data = {
  names: ["Scott","Mary","Tom"],
  addresses: ["10 Main", "23 Elm", "43 Standish"],
  phoneNums: ["555-555-5555","123-456-7890"],
  grades: ["C", "B-", "A+"],
  schools: ["District 1", "District 2", "District 3"]
};

// These map to the object properties and will be used to extract the right data
var keyNames = ["names", "addresses", "phoneNums", "grades", "schools"];

var output = document.querySelector(".output"); // The output element

// Get all the buttons and divs into Arrays:
let buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".roundBtns"));

// Set up a single click event handler on the parent element of the buttons
document.querySelector(".btn-group").addEventListener("click", function(evt){

  // Get the index of the button that was clicked within its group
  var clickedIndex = buttons.indexOf(evt.target);
  
  // Inject the string into the output div
  output.innerHTML = data[keyNames[clickedIndex]].join("<br>");;
});
```

```html
<div class="myButtons">
  <div class="btn-group" id="MatchingEntitiesButtons">
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Names</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Address</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Phone#</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Grades</button>
    <button class="roundBtns" type="button">List of Schools</button>  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

And, to really reduce the complexity, don't bother with a separate `div` for each button that gets clicked. Just have one `div` and simply change what's in it depending on what button gets clicked: