# How to show and hide a div using javascript without calling any function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show and hide a div based on a condition. Please help me do this.
This my code:

```
<script> 
  var shad = '{SUBJECT}';       
  if (shad != "") {
    document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = 'show';
  }
</script>

<div  id="subjectr">
  sub
  <input type="text" name="subjectr">
</div>
```

Comment: add `ID` in you `input` code `<input type="text" name="subjectr" id="subjectr">`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript

Comment: i want to show and hide div without write any function ..it is possible??please correct my above code..@Kapila Perera

Comment: `show` is not a valid value of `display` It should be `block` or `inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var shad ='SUBJECT';      
if (shad !="") {
  document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = 'none';
}
else {
  document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
sub: <input type="text" name="subjectr" id="subjectr" value='SUBJECT'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var shad ='SUBJECT';        
  if (shad != "") {
    document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("subjectr").style.display = 'block';
  }
```