# Javascript: How to show only one div on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div in a html file.

```
<div class="one" id="firstDiv">
</div>

<div class="Two" id="SecondDiv">
</div>
```

I want to show only div class = "one" when the page loads and eventually show div two when a click action occurs. I know how to fade in onclick event but how can I only show the first div when the page loads?

Comment: you can make class= "Two" display:none and make it available onclick as mentioned

Comment: You can omit the second div and create it programmatically on button click. Or you can add a class that hides it initially and remove it on button click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below option
Option 1:
1.Create function to hide the div using id
2.Use function on body as onload function
Codepen url for reference- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JNNrpM

Option 2:
1. Make #SecondDiv display:none initially
2. And make it available onclick using display:block
Codepen url for reference- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KmmXez

JS:

```
var divTwo = document.getElementById('SecondDiv');
function hideDiv(){
  divTwo.style.display ='none';
}

function showDiv(){
  divTwo.style.display ='block';
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body onload="hideDiv()">
    <div class="one" id="firstDiv">111
</div>

<div class="Two" id="SecondDiv">222
</div>

    <button onclick="showDiv()">show Div Two</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Option2:**

```
HTML:

<html>
  <body>
    <div class="one" id="firstDiv">111
</div>

<div class="Two" id="SecondDiv">222
</div>

    <button onclick="showDiv()">show Div Two</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.Two{
  display:none
}
```

JS:

```
function showDiv(){
  var divTwo = document.getElementById('SecondDiv');
  divTwo.style.display ='block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a click event so that when the body is clicked, you add the other div to the page with `createElement()`:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

If you only want the div to be added once, you can remove the event listener along with the creation of the div.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `div` to be hidden at the start you could use CSS to apply the hidden value such as:

```
<div class="hidden" id="someIdVal">Lorem Ipsum</div>

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Then with JS remove/add the class with:

```
function toggleHidden(id){
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.Two{display:none;}

And then with javascript onclick event:

document.getElementById("SecondDiv").style.display = "block";