# Show/Hide element by ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function showhide(id) {
  obj = document.getElementById(id);

  if (obj.style.display == 'none' || obj.style.display == null)
    obj.style.display = 'block';
  else
    obj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#stuff {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('stuff'); return false;">Click Me</a>

<div id="stuff">
  secret stuff
</div>
```

This kinda works but require two clicks. It seems that it can’t detect that the state is `null`.

Apparently if I change the condition to this it works:

```
if (obj.style.display == 'block')
        obj.style.display  = 'none';
else
        obj.style.display  = 'block';
```

My question now is, what is wrong with the first condition?

Comment: It isn't `null`.  Use the debugger to figure out what it is.

Comment: Edit your post with `console.log(obj.style.display)` result, please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/72Lx1s8a/ works with your first example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: @JordanS if you put the CSS, it won't

Comment: Your first example should work if you remove the null check.  If it's "none" - that is the only time it will be hidden.  If it's "anything else" it will be displayed.

Comment: Add this comparison to your if `obj.style.display == ''`and it will work

Comment: @James It won’t work if the `null` check is removed, because `obj.style.display` still isn’t `"none"` at the very beginning.

Comment: Oh right because he's using a css rule to hide it rather than setting the display attribute on the element, gotcha

Answer (score 1):

If the element's display is being specified by a CSS rule, you'll need to get it's computed style. What you're doing would work if you were replacing an inline style on the div.

```js
function showhide (id)
{
    obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var displayStyle = obj.currentStyle ? obj.currentStyle.display :
                          getComputedStyle(obj, null).display;
    if (displayStyle == 'none' || displayStyle == null)
        obj.style.display  = 'block';
    else
        obj.style.display  = 'none';
}
```

```css
#stuff { display:none; }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showhide('stuff'); return false;">Click Me</a>

<div id="stuff">
    secret stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself: at what point is `obj.style.display` ever `null`? If you actually log it to the console, you’ll get `""`.

In your first code `obj.style.display` is neither `"none"` nor `""`, so the `else` case is executed: it’ll be set to `"none"`. It already isn’t displayed, but only because of a CSS rule, not a direct `style` property on the element itself.

Your second code works because it implies that `""` and `"none"` behave the same way and `"block"` behaves differently, which is actually the case (if you only use `"none"` and `"block"`).

Answer (score 0):

You could set the display attribute of the element directly rather than using CSS, so:

```
<div id="stuff" style="display:none">
  secret stuff
</div>
```

and get rid of

```
#stuff { display:none; }
```

Then your first example (the null check is not needed) would work.