# show or hide divs depending on input value

Tags: javascript

I have an input[type=range], user can select a value (for example, from 0 to 1000), this is kinda price filter, also I have several divs each one with it's own pricevalue. I need div to be shown or hide depending on input values. How to do this with VanillaJS?

Comment: Can you post some your code to understand what actually is not working?  Here is a [great answer about showing/hiding elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070237/4222181) in general without using any libs.

Comment: I created a Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kpanyushin/9h6gk7s6/

Comment: when input's value is less then span's value, div.block should be hidden. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this hardcoded, or are they dynamic divs? Have you tried just getting the value of the input and hiding the divs that are required?

```
if(input.val < 1000){
    var divToHide = document.getElementById("priceMid");
    divToHide.style.display = 'none';           // Hide
}
```

if you have multiple divs, give each one their own attribute with the value, and then you can iterate over them and only hide the ones above/below a certain value. This answer has more in detail [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)