# Show and hide image js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to toggle the visibility on and off. So the second click on the button should hide the image again. How do I do this?

This is my current code which only toggles the hidden .png on.

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage(){
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
    }
</script>

<input id="text" type="button" value="Explosion Button" onclick="showImage();"/>
<img id="loadingImage" src="explosions.png" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You seriously can't have searched very hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in many ways.
A basic sample  .Check if the element is visible if yes the hide else show the element

```js
function showImage(){
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility=    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility == 'visible'? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
```

```html
<div>  
  <input id="text" type="button" value="Explosion Button" onclick="showImage();"/>
  <img id="loadingImage" src="explosions.png" style="visibility:hidden"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, but how do I apply this if I have more than 1 button that needs to hide and show an image? I edited a second with with "showImage2" and "loadingImage2", but they won't work together with the existing show/hide button.

Comment: @Celfurion there are many ways to hide and show a div.You can check this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript