# PHP hide div after another page is loaded

Tags: php, html

I have am trying to get simple php dynamic web together.
I have this code to load links to the div.

I would like instead of echo "Welcome to my new page"; to close div which is messing up the opened page.

Big Thanks

Comment: post your code please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do... Do keep in mind PHP is a server language, therefore you won't be able to interact with UI elements at live time with PHP (PHP runs the code `onload`), for that you need to look at JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is only possible with Javascript.

Comment: This type of answer would more be suited to a comment

Comment: Hi, here is my website http://trev-sample.wladonline.eu/RRL/index.php
You can see this msg there "Are you ready to put the skates
on, and prove you have what it 
takes to be the best?"
When you click on any link for example Rules I would like this msg which is in div do hide.
Thanks