# How to show/hide content on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some content in p tag

```
<p>Some Content</p>
```

I also have two button 'Hide' and 'Show'.

```
<button>Hide</button>
<button>Show</button>
```

I want to hide the content if i click on 'Hide' button and show it again if clicked on 'Show' button. How to do it? Using JS or JQuery?

Comment: Did you googled before posting this question?

Comment: this site id for help in your code...

Comment: I have my uncle google who can really help you.. ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

<p>Some Content</p>

<button onclick=" $('p').hide();">Hide</button>
<button onclick=" $('p').show();">Show</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is the simplest answer among all, i don't know why someone voted you down.

Comment: @WeirdDude this is voted down because it uses `onclick` attributes, which is the worst way to attach events and should be avoided where at all possible. All the other answers are better solutions that this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a very basic question, use some basic jquery `hide()` and `show()` function. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('#hide').click(function() {
  $('.content').hide();
});
$('#show').click(function() {
  $('.content').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="content">Some Content</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```