# Show div on click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to make a div appear and disappear using javascript, but it's not working.I've included the javascript file(where the function is),but I don't understand why it's not working.

When I press the button, nothing happens.

HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="show_on_click.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none" class="answer_list">Button Test</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" value="Test"/>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function ShowDiv(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Do you have errors in your JS console? Are you sure your function `ShowDiv` is called when you click on the button?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: You need to put the script after the button - what does "html and body tags are open in the header" mean? Press F12 and see that you get ShowDiv is not defined

Comment: Your code is only making it to visible, first check whether is visible, if visible, then hide. if hidden then make it visible. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: You also want to toggle the display

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript

Comment: @sjahan, the function it's not even called.I've tried to display a text instead the style.display just to be sure, but it's not working.

Comment: @Chidambaram I will check the link and i will come back with a reply.Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none" class="answer_list">Button Test</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" value="Test"/>

<script>
  function ShowDiv(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = 'block';
  }
</script>
```

There are one or both of two errors:

- your src path for script is wrong
- somewhere you redefine function for button

Comment: Omg...Yep,it was a src path problem.Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Another problem will be: you are only set display to `block`, not to `none` again.

Try this:

```
function ShowDiv() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    if (element.style.display === 'none') {
        element.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: However the code needs to run after the button exists. That is problem #1