# Problem showing/hiding UI elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have written some HTML to display/hide some UI when buttons are clicked.  I want the UI to be hidden when the page loads and revealed when the "Show UI" button is clicked.

The following HTML almost works:

```js
function showHide(thingToHide, thingToShow) {
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Shown";
  if (thingToHide == "showUI") {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Hidden";
  }
  document.getElementById(thingToHide).style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById(thingToShow).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<div id="hideUI">
  <input id="showButton" type="button" onclick="showHide('hideUI', 'showUI');" value="Show UI" />
</div>

<div id="showUI">
  <input id="hideButton" type="button" onclick="showHide('showUI', 'hideUI');" value="Hide UI" />
  <p> Various UI goes here</p>
</div>
<p id="status">Start</p>
```

However, the "showUI" div is visible when the page first displays.  If I set the initial visibility to hidden in that div, it does not show up as expected when I click the "Show UI" button and attempt to make it visible.

```
<div id="showUI" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the function once in the script. See in below code, I have called `showHide('show', 'hideUI');` just after declaring the function.

```js
function showHide(thingToHide, thingToShow) {
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Shown";
  if (thingToHide == "showUI") {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Hidden";
  }
  document.getElementById(thingToHide).style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById(thingToShow).style.visibility = "visible";
}
showHide('showUI', 'hideUI');
```

```html
<div id="hideUI">
  <input id="showButton" type="button" onclick="showHide('hideUI', 'showUI');" value="Show UI" />
</div>

<div id="showUI">
  <input id="hideButton" type="button" onclick="showHide('showUI', 'hideUI');" value="Hide UI" />
  <p> Various UI goes here</p>
</div>
<p id="status">Start</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute showHide('hideUI', 'showUI'); when loading the page. 
The following Javascript should work:

```
function showHide(thingToHide, thingToShow) {
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Shown";
  if (thingToHide == "showUI") {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Hidden";
  }
  document.getElementById(thingToHide).style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById(thingToShow).style.visibility = "visible";
}
showHide('hideUI', 'showUI');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my original code is that the javascript function is BEFORE the divs.  If I set the visibility of div showUI to hidden in the HTML and I move the javascript after the HTML for the divs it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for. It keeps the button in the same place.

HTML

```
<input id="Button" type="button" onclick="showHide('UI');" value="Show UI" />
<div id="UI" style="visibility: hidden">
    <p> Various UI goes here</p>
</div>
<p id="status">Start</p>
```

JS

```
function showHide(UI) {
  if (document.getElementById(UI).style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Shown";
    document.getElementById(UI).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('Button').value = 'Hide UI'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Hidden";
    document.getElementById(UI).style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('Button').value = 'Show UI'
  }
```