# Confused on How to Tab This Content

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I wrote this code with the aim of creating tabs with them. Built on someone else's code. The plan was to create blocks and then create tabs with those blocks. If you use Shopify then you know what I mean but I'll post the full code here for you to see. Currently out of ideas on how to create the tabs...thinking of a for loop to put them into a list but can't seem to wrap my head around making that work, perhaps that's even a wrong way to go...?

Here's the **section code**:

```html
{% comment %}
** Single featured collection - homepage partial **
- Draggable section
{% endcomment %}

{% include 'include-featured-collection-custom' %}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Featured collection Cust",
  "class": "featured-collection-section",
  "max_blocks": 6,
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Custom Featured collection"
    } 
],
   "blocks": [
    {
  "type": "collection",
  "name": "Tabbed Collection",
  "settings": [
       {
           "type": "collection",
           "id": "collection",
           "label": "Collection"
          },
       {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "tabtitle",
      "label": "Tab Title",
      "default": "Tab Title"
       },
                      {
                        "type": "radio",
                        "id": "collection_style",
                        "label": "Collection layout",
                        "default": "slider",
                        "options": [
                          {
                            "value": "slider",
                            "label": "Slider"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "grid",
                            "label": "Grid"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "range",
                        "id": "products_per",
                        "label": "Products per row",
                        "min": 2,
                        "max": 7,
                        "step": 1,
                        "default": 3
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "range",
                        "id": "products_limit",
                        "label": "Limit products",
                        "min": 3,
                        "max": 20,
                        "step": 1,
                        "default": 5
                      }
     ]
  }
  ],
  "presets": [{
    "name": "Featured collection Cust",
    "category": "Collection",
    "settings": {

    },
 "blocks": [
        { 
          "type": "collection"
        },
        {
          "type": "collection"
        },
  {
    "type": "collection"
  }
      ]
  }]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Here's the **snippet code**:

```html
  {% assign title = section.settings.title %}

<div class="container featured_products product-{{ collection_style }}">
  <div class="sixteen columns center homepage_content">
    {% if title != blank %}
      <a href="{{ collections[settingCollection].url }}"><h2 class="title">{{ title }}</h2></a>
      <div class="feature_divider"></div>
    {% endif %}
    {% if collection_description and collections[settingCollection].description != blank %}
      <div class="section clearfix">
        {{ collections[settingCollection].description }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  {% assign settingCollection = block.settings.collection %}
  {% assign collection_style = block.settings.collection_style %}
  {% assign collection_description = block.settings.collection_description %}
  {% assign products_per = block.settings.products_per %}
  {% assign products_limit = block.settings.products_limit %}


{% if settingCollection == blank %}
  {%- assign section_onboarding = true -%}
  {% comment %}assign product length to be selected limit for onboarding{% endcomment %}
  {% assign products_length = products_limit | plus: 0 %}
{% else %}
  {%- assign section_onboarding = false -%}
{% endif %}



{% assign limit = products_limit %}

{% if collection_style == 'slider' %}
  {% assign col = settingCollection %}
  {% assign products = collections[settingCollection].products %}
  {% assign per_slide = products_per %}

  <div class="container js-product-slider homepage-product-slider full-width--true {% if per_slide == 2 or per_slide == 4 or per_slide == 6 %}even-num-slides{% endif %}">
    <a href=""><h3 class="title" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;border: 1px solid;width: 200px;padding: 5px;"> {{ block.settings.tabtitle }} </h3></a>
    {% if section_onboarding == false %}
      {% if col and collections[col].all_products_count > 0 %}
        {% include 'product-slider', per_slide: products_per, featured_collection: col  %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}

      <div class="slider-gallery products-slider products-length-{{ products_length }}"
            data-products-per-slide="{{ per_slide }}"
            data-products-limit="{{ limit }}"
            data-products-available="{{ products_length }}">
        {% for i in (1..limit) %}
          {% assign per_slide_num = products_per | plus: 0 %}
          <div class="gallery-cell thumbnail
          {% if products_length > per_slide_num %}visible-{{ per_slide }}{% else %}visible-{{ products_length }}{% endif %}
          ">
            <div class="product-wrap">
              <div class="relative product_image">
                <a href="#" itemprop="url">
                  <object class="placeholder-image">
                    {% capture num %}{% cycle "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" %}{% endcapture %}
                    {{ 'product-' | append: num | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg placeholder-svg--product' }}
                  </object>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% else %}
  {% if section_onboarding == false %}
    {% assign limit = products_limit %}
    {% assign collection = collections[settingCollection] %}
    {% assign products = collections[settingCollection].products %}
    {% assign products_per_row = products_per %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sixteen columns">
        {% include 'product-loop' %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% else %}
    {% assign products_per_row = products_per %}
    <div class="container equal-columns--outside-trim">
      <div class="sixteen columns">
        {% capture new_row %}
            <br class="clear product_clear" />
        {% endcapture %}

        <div itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList" class="product-list collection-matrix clearfix">
          {% for i in (1..limit) %}
            {% comment %}{% assign collection_group = products | map: 'id' %}{% endcomment %}
            {% assign collection_group_thumb = collection_group | append : 'thumb' %}
            {% assign collection_group_mobile = collection_group | append : 'mobile' %}
              <div class="
              {% if products_per_row == 2 %}
                eight columns {% cycle collection_group_thumb: 'alpha', 'omega' %}
              {% elsif products_per_row == 3 %}
                one-third column {% cycle collection_group_thumb: 'alpha', '', 'omega' %}
              {% elsif products_per_row == 4 %}
                four columns {% cycle collection_group_thumb: 'alpha', '', '', 'omega' %}
              {% elsif products_per_row == 5 %}
                one-fifth column {% cycle collection_group_thumb: 'alpha', '', '', '', 'omega' %}
              {% elsif products_per_row == 6 %}
                one-sixth column {% cycle collection_group_thumb: 'alpha', '', '', '', '', 'omega' %}
              {% else %}
                one-seventh column {% cycle collection_group_thumb: 'alpha', '', '', '', '', '', 'omega' %}
              {% endif %} thumbnail {% cycle collection_group_mobile: 'even', 'odd' %}
              {% if settings.mobile_products_per_row == '1' %}
                medium-down--one-half
                small-down--one-whole
              {% else %}
                medium-down--one-half
                small-down--one-half
              {% endif %}">

              <div class="product-wrap">
                <div class="relative product_image swap-{{ settings.collection_secondary_image }}">
                  <a href="#" itemprop="url">
                    {% capture num %}{% cycle "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" %}{% endcapture %}
                    {{ 'product-' | append: num | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg placeholder-svg--product' }}
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {% if products_per_row == 2 %}
              {% cycle collection_group: '', new_row %}
            {% elsif products_per_row == 3 %}
              {% cycle collection_group: '', '', new_row %}
            {% elsif products_per_row == 4 %}
              {% cycle collection_group: '', '', '', new_row %}
            {% elsif products_per_row == 5 %}
              {% cycle collection_group: '', '', '', '', new_row %}
            {% elsif products_per_row == 6 %}
              {% cycle collection_group: '', '', '', '', '', new_row %}
            {% elsif products_per_row == 7 %}
              {% cycle collection_group: '', '', '', '', '', '', new_row %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And here's the **front end result** so far.
[image: front end screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Can you provide a rough mockup how should the section tab look since from the provided code I don't see any tab logic? In addition consider triming down the code to only the important parts (for example we don't need to see 20 lines of `if` checks for applying a class if it has nothing to do with the problem at hand).

Comment: Hi drip. That's what I'm trying to do: loop each iteration into a list which I can then use CSS to make into tabs but I'm not so certain that's what I need and just trying to get ideas. For instance, I was thinking of using Javascript and making each iteration into a div of it's own and have javascript pull the tab title as a tab title and then pull the div depending on which title is clicked.

Comment: Hide the sections by default and use an active class to show any tab section. You need to add some JS to add an active class to each tab. Here are some ways to do that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript