# how to implement visibility gone in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to hide div element and remove div on button clicked. I am new to javascript but worked on android. In android we are having feature of `visibility:hidden` or `visibility:gone`. how to implement it with javascript.

I just found `document.getElementById("id").style.visibility="hidden";`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok then you found this, have you tried this? Post your code. Tell us what worked for you, what didn't

Comment: you can google answer for that in one search

Comment: in google search "hide div javascript", you will get first link to do this. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"` to hide the div and `document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block"` to show it

[w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) has a greate guide on this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV"); //so we dont have to write doc.get multiple times
  if (x.style.display === "none") { //check if hidden
    x.style.display = "block"; //display it
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none"; //hide it
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: whatever he have done that will also work. `document.getElementById("id").style.visibility="hidden";`

Comment: @Kaushik Yes but the looks of it he only needs to understand how to implement it, so he can try it himself

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
<div id="myDIV"> TEST </div>

JS
function myFunction() {
var z = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (z.style.display === "none") {z.style.display === "block"; }
else {z.style.display = "none" }}
```