# Auto Show Hide DIV Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

One little doubt in javascript accept this code

```
$('#B').css("display", "none" : "block");
```

if  div B is `display: none` on event auto switch to block

Comment: which event you want to change ?

Comment: That's not valid syntax... Can you explain your question better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Did you mean [`$("#B").toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Answer (score 0):

On init you could check using jQuery's [**`:hidden`** selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
// App init:
$('#B:visible').hide();
```

than if you need to **[.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** it on some event:

```
// Some event:
$('#B').toggle();
```

Example:

```js
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function() {
  $(this.dataset.toggle).toggle();
});
```

```html
<button data-toggle="#B" type="button">Toggle B</button>
<div id="B">Lorem ut florem</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A preferred way, instead of using jQuery's show/hide/toggle methods is to use `.toggleClass()` and define in CSS the needed styles

```js
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function() {
  $(this.dataset.toggle).toggleClass("is-hidden");
});
```

```css
/* Bool helpers */
.is-hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<button data-toggle="#B" type="button">Toggle B</button>
<div id="B" class="is-hidden">Lorem ut florem</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```