# How to "cycle" through elements (show/hide) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that includes elements like these:

```js
<div id="1" style="display: block;">
[...]
</div>
    
<div id="2" style="display: none;">
[...]
</div>
    
<div id="3" style="display: none;">
[...]
</div>
    
<button id="next" onclick="ScrollNext()">
    
<button id="previous" onclick="ScrollPrevious()">
```

When a user clicks "next", I want to determine which [div] is currently showing as "display: block;" modify that [div]'s style to "display: none;", and then modify the next sequential [div]'s style to "display: block;" (and of course I want to do the opposite when the user clicks the "previous" button)

I know how to write code for a button to toggle a single element this way, but how can I determine programmatically which element's style to modify?

Comment: What have you tried so far to make it work? If you attempt to solve it rather than asking for a ready-made solution and have a concrete problem, you'll probably learn more and get higher-quality answers.

Comment: Take a look at [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then try to make your attempt, if you find a problem post another question or edit this one.

Comment: Skip the "style"-approach and work with "class" instead. Name one class "visible" the other "invisible" for example. And then just switch classes in order to show or hide a div.

Comment: @Jake Why not [edit your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958395/is-there-a-javascript-library-that-allows-a-user-to-cycle-through-certain-elem) instead of reposting?

Comment: @ggorlen - I made the mistake of assuming that doing so would be frowned upon. So the better practice is to make the question better fit SO's guidelines and then reopen it?

Comment: Yep. The post closure banner says "You can edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." Then it'll enter the reopen queue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an implementation using JavaScript as below. I have given distinct color to the `div` for the sake of observing the change. We basically make use of `nextElementSibling` and `previousElementSibling` properties of the `Node` to cycle forward and backward. Finding the current visible node is just a `.find` away.

```js
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container')];

function getVisibleDiv() {
  const visibleDiv = divs.find(div => div.style.display === 'block');
  return visibleDiv;
}

function next() {
  const visibleDiv = getVisibleDiv();
  visibleDiv.style.display = 'none';
  if (visibleDiv.nextElementSibling?.className === 'container')
    visibleDiv.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  else {
    divs[0].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function previous() {
  const visibleDiv = getVisibleDiv();
  visibleDiv.style.display = 'none';
  if (visibleDiv.previousElementSibling?.className === 'container')
    visibleDiv.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  else {
    divs[divs.length - 1].style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.container:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
}

.container:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class='container' style="display: block;">

</div>

<div id="2" class='container' style="display: none;">

</div>

<div id="3" class='container' style="display: none;">

</div>

<button id="next" onclick="next()">Next</button>

<button id="previous" onclick="previous()">Prev</button>
```