# How to hide a js div with css

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to remove the "powered by tagembed" text and image .

```js
hide(document.querySelectorAll('.poweredbywrapper'));

function hide(elements) {
  elements = elements.length ? elements : [elements];
  for (var index = 0; index < elements.length - 1; index++) {
    elements[index].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.poweredbywrapper img,
.poweredbywrapper span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagembed-container" style=" width:100%;height:500px;overflow: auto;">
  <div class="tagembed-socialwall" data-wall-id="11530" view-url="https://widget.tagembed.com/11530?view"> </div>
  <script src="//widget.tagembed.com/embed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

and other classes but its not working

Comment: It is inside an Iframe, you cannot access the style from the parent, it has to be done from the source of the iframe which looks to be `https://widget.tagembed.com/11530?wix`

Comment: Please share more details, like the markup that is involved

Comment: It appears that this is a paid product, for which you'd need to buy a subscription in order to remove the watermark. Note that removing this watermark without express permission from the product's creator might violate their license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS property. Does it worked?

```
.poweredbywrapper img, .poweredbywrapper span {
    visibility: hidden;
 }
```

a) ***The display: none*** rule removes an element from an HTML document. While the code for the hidden element is still present, the element itself will not be displayed.

b) ***The visibility: hidden*** rule, on the other hand, hides an element, but the element will still take up space on the web page. If you want to hide an element but keep that element’s space on the web page, using the visibility: hidden; rule is best.

Follow this another link for hiding a js div element.

[Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```

<script>
    hide(document.querySelectorAll('.poweredbywrapper'));

function hide (elements) {
  elements = elements.length ? elements : [elements];
  for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
    elements[index].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>

```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually have the class that you try to hide:

```
<div class="tagembed-container poweredbywrapper" style=" width:100%;height:500px;overflow: auto;"><div class="tagembed-socialwall" data-wall-id="11530" view-url="https://widget.tagembed.com/11530?view">  </div> <script src="//widget.tagembed.com/embed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div>
```