# How to disappear/appear content in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to appear/disappear a `<div>` in a html file from a javascript function. How can I do that?

Comment: You can change its `display` style from `block` to `none`. Either by assigning the `style` property or by changing a class that has these styles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a real simple way.

```js
function togglehide(id){

    var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.classList.toggle('hideme');
  
}
```

```css
.hideme{display:none}
```

```html
<button onclick="togglehide('mydiv')">Click me</button>
<br>
<div id="mydiv">
put some content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select it, then set either its `style`, or add a CSS class that does the hiding.

```js
document.querySelector("#element-id").classList.toggle("d-none");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
div.style.display = 'none'; // this will make it as if it didn't exist
div.style.opacity = 0 // this will make it transparent
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the style property to none which hides the content.

```
document.getElementById("element").style.display = "none";
```